# Why will my program not play the next song in the array?

Tags: java, audio-player

I have been working on this code for a really long time and i just can't seem to figure out my problem. i want to be able to play a list of songs one right after another and i thought i would be able to do that with a simple recursive method that delays the average length of a song, and have it call the next song and play it... However it only plays the very first song and then stops after that and nothing else happens... I have asked countless people to look at this and nobody can help me out.. And no this is not a school project, it is a music player that my mother would like me to use at a party in the next upcoming weekend, so this is like my last ditch effort... Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
private JLabel messageLabel;
private JButton playlist;
private JPanel panel;
BufferedImage image;
AudioStream audioStream1, audioStream2, audioStream3;
//Object[] music = new Object[3];
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 525;

// File destinationss    
private String s1 = "C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Java\\NetBeansProjects\\Gui Stuff\\src\\No_Pressure.wav";
private String s2 = "C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Java\\NetBeansProjects\\Gui Stuff\\src\\Grateful_Dead_-_Touch_of_Grey.wav";
private String s3 = "C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Java\\NetBeansProjects\\Gui Stuff\\src\\Stairway_to_Heaven_Led_Zeppelin_Lyrics.wav";

InputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(s1);
InputStream in2 = new FileInputStream(s2);
InputStream in3 = new FileInputStream(s3);
private ArrayList music;

public JukeBoxWithArrays() throws IOException {

    music = new ArrayList();

    audioStream1 = new AudioStream(in1);
    audioStream2 = new AudioStream(in2);
    audioStream3 = new AudioStream(in3);

    music.add(audioStream1);
    music.add(audioStream2);
    music.add(audioStream3);

    setTitle("Juke Box Playlist");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    messageLabel = new JLabel("Click the Button to play the playlist");

    // Create the Playlist button
    playlist = new JButton("Playlist number 1");

    // Register the event Listener
    playlist.addActionListener(new PlaylistListener());

    // Create the panel
    panel = new JPanel();
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Java\\NetBeansProjects\\Gui Stuff\\src\\jukebox2.jpg"));
    panel.add(messageLabel);
    panel.add(playlist);
    panel.add((new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image))));

    // Add the panel to the Content Pane
    add(panel);

    // Display the Window
    setVisible(true);
}

private class PlaylistListener implements ActionListener {

    int x = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            playMusic(x);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JukeBoxWithArrays.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void playMusic(int x) throws InterruptedException {

        if (x > music.size()) {
            AudioPlayer.player.stop((InputStream) music.get(x));

        } else {
            AudioPlayer.player.start((InputStream) music.get(x));

        }
        Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); // I believe this is where I am running into my problem
        playMusic(x++);

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JukeBoxWithArrays jbwa = new JukeBoxWithArrays();
    jbwa.pack();

}
```

}

Comment: OK I will not ask you why your mother want you to use this instead of spotify... anyway... where this code come from? Did you tried to debug it? Why you think that thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000) is causing the issue?

Comment: I think that is causing the issue because before I added that, the method worked, but the songs would play over top of one another. So all I was trying to do was space them apart so one would play and then the next and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code is failing for the same reason this:

```
private static int x = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    int x = 0;
    doSomething(x);
    doSomething(x);
    doSomething(x);
    doSomething(x);
    doSomething(x);
}

private static void doSomething(int x) {
    System.out.println(x++);
}
```

Outputs this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Your Listener has an `x` field, that your are **passing by value** between the methods. You should remove the `x` argument on `playMusic()`, so everytime it increments `x`, it would use the object field instead.

Comment: Use  playMusic(++x);

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help

Comment: Logically in my head that should print 1 everytime.. So what you're saying is that I need to first increment X then call the method?

Comment: So would it be like this? public void playMusic()

Comment: Yes, that covers the main problem. You should review your whole logic, though.